# Does MongoDB support soundex or fuzzy matching?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, soundex

Does MongoDB support soundex or fuzzy matching?  I want to spot dupes of basic contact name and address fields.  I'm using the official C# driver.  Thanks

Comment: read this article [How to perform fuzzy matching with mongo connector](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/how-to-perform-fuzzy-matching-with-mongo-connector)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Mongodb doesn't support soundex matching, but it has [Full Text Search](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-text/).

Also,

> You can always just store the
>   soundex-encoded string in a separate
>   field in mongo and search against
>   that. [Soundex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundex) is a really trivial
>   algorithm and should only take a handful of
>   lines.

-- from [mongodb-user](http://groups.google.com/group/mongodb-user/browse_thread/thread/1372fca2e2912026/e1d20bff7236b714?lnk=raot)

Comment: MongoDB has no real fulltext search. Pattern matching is no fulltext search.

Comment: You should have quoted the followup of your quote...sorry but using soundex for this purpose is just a bad idea.

Comment: @AndreasJung: in the meantime MongoDB has implemented FTS. Let's delete our comments.